Having trouble creating SPLs in local environment - both CLI & JS packages
I'm trying to create some token mints locally, and it's just not working - both spl-token create-token and the JS version of the same just hang.
I'm certain that the validator node is running and healthy. I've had success deploying SPL tokens to devnet, but really need to do so locally.

There might be an issue with your local node setup, so be sure you can first query your balance using solana -ul balance or send transactions to it with solana -ul ping
